# Writing to console in c#: can you single writeline with multiple colors, or lock the console to do multiple writes?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-console, console.writeline

I want to put a string with more than one color onto the console and have it perform as if it were a single WriteLine, as opposed to multiple writes which could get interrupted, or corrupted by other threads writing at the same time.

So the post below looked like it was going in the right direction, but I do not control all the code that is writing to the console. My code is restricted to the dll that I am authoring, so I can't just go putting locks everywhere that could interfere. If it were a question of locks and understanding of threading there would be no question. Is this even possible without locks in my code?

[How do I lock the console across threads in C#.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522936/how-do-i-lock-the-console-across-threads-in-c-net)

Comment: How many threads will write to console? how many places in code you have `WriteLine` calls. ?

Comment: I suppose I have it working well enough without the lock.... but I know that it is possible for things to come out wrong and that bugs me. ... but we can't know what code will be writing to the console, and I cant tell other developers "hey use this lock when doing this" (I'd rather have it come out wrong once in a blue blue moon). However it seems unlikely that allot of messages from other code will come up to the console, I can not control this.

Comment: I have only one line to write. admittedly it will get hit often, as it is a logger line similar to the one in the other post I linked to.

Comment: Then lock is enough. Or if you want a lockfree impl use a `Queue` and have a Threadpool thread which dispatches queue data and writes to console then exits when queue is empty, again doing the same\

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel Um, how will the other threads (parent processes outside my dll) know about the lock?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by parent processes? you mean another process? I think servy has given a good idea for you. go for it

Comment: I believe that the problem I pose is unsolvable, based on the responses so far: If you are only writing a library or an API where a controlling application using your code is outside of your code base accesses the Console Window, it appears that the controlling application that is using the api or library can break what ever attempts you make to lock the console window unless you control that code as well. I recognise that my use of the word process is incorrect, I should have said parent application I think. I was not talking about a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the existing output stream with a TextWriter of your own using `Console.SetOut`.  In your custom text writer have it synchronize access to the console on some object and then write back to the *real* standard output, as well as providing some means for the helper method that you have to also be able to synchronize on that same object, that way whenever that helper method is running it can lock access to the console for the rest of the application.

Comment: Umm, please elaborate on "synchronize access to the console on some object".

Comment: @amalgamate You use the `lock` keyword, and pass in a single object instances throughout all calls to `Write`.  Your question gave the impression you were familiar with basic inter thread synchronization.

Comment: Umm. But other code is writing to the console. Code I do not own, and do not control. I can't lock all write events to the console. I can put a lock around this textWriter I create, but what good is that? How does it involve/engage the console and allow me to use multiple colors on a single line?

Comment: @amalgamate As I said in my answer, you would replace the console's output stream with your own, that would mean that all calls to `Console.Write` would be sent to your textwriter.  That's the crux of this answer.

Comment: OK so I begin to see... but just to be sure, Calls to Console.ForegroundColor too? Wow, if so thanks.

Comment: @amalgamate No, changing the color wouldn't send anything to the textwriter, which is why the second half of the answer is there.

Comment: So what does this helper method Do? You only say I have one.

Comment: @amalgamate That's the non-atomic console writing that you want to do atomically.  It can do whatever, and do so while knowing that no console writes take place from other threads while it's happening.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37672/discussion-between-amalgamate-and-servy)