# How can I insure that the console and or keyboard is in insert mode using c# code?

Tags: c#, windows-console

How do I access the Windows Console API for the console from C#. Specifically how do I exploit the [SetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property for the Console? Is there a big performance cost? or Is there another way to set the Console's mode in C#?

Comment: It is already in insert mode by default.  Just try it with a Console.ReadLine() call, type something, use the left cursor key and type something.  What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @HansPassant That is definitely useful info. I want to somehow insure that some threaded console.writes stay together, while others are separate, and of course I want to avoid locks.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing that SetConsoleMode() can do to make that easier.  Of course you need a lock.

Comment: @HansPassant I started with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896404/writing-to-console-in-c-can-you-single-writeline-with-multiple-colors-or-lock/18897064?noredirect=1#comment27895314_18897064. My gut says that Servy is giving the answer to my problem, or a good answer to my problem, however I do not quite see the whole picture despite his patient efforts.

Comment: I was thinking that I could insert at the correct spot in the line, but I see why that wont be a good solution now.